# Spartacus ASM giving 403 ForbiddenError while starting customer session

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

1. Login with asagent in SPA- ASM
2. Search the customer (its returning the customer)
3. while starting the session it hits

https://localhost:9002/occ/v2/{basesiteid}/users/{userid}?lang=en&curr=abc its is giving
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 403

Response:

```
{
   "errors" : [ {
      "message" : "Access is denied",
      "type" : "ForbiddenError"
   } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in asagent ( Employee) add a group customermanagergroup ( Customer Manager Group ) this will solve the issue